# How to wait for user reply in aiogram

Tags: python-3.x, async-await, telegram-bot, aiogram

How can I write awaiting of user reply on aiogram?
It needs to be like:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"]):
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Send me your name")
    name = # Here I need a user input
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use [FSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine), which is a built-in feature of aiogram.

Example for your case:

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup


bot = Bot(token='BOT TOKEN HERE')

# Don't forget to use storage, otherwise answers won't be saved.
# You can find all supported storages here:
# https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/tree/dev-2.x/aiogram/contrib/fsm_storage
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


class Form(StatesGroup):
    name = State()


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    """Conversation entrypoint"""

    # Set state
    await Form.name.set()
    await message.reply("Send me your name")


# You can use state='*' if you want to handle all states
@dp.message_handler(state='*', commands=['cancel'])
async def cancel_handler(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    """Allow user to cancel action via /cancel command"""

    current_state = await state.get_state()
    if current_state is None:
        # User is not in any state, ignoring
        return

    # Cancel state and inform user about it
    await state.finish()
    await message.reply('Cancelled.')


@dp.message_handler(state=Form.name)
async def process_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    """Process user name"""

    # Finish our conversation
    await state.finish()
    await message.reply(f"Hello, {message.text}")  # <-- Here we get the name
```

And this is how it looks like:

[image: code above in action]

[Official documentation](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/dispatcher/fsm.html) for aiogram FSM is quite bad, but there's [an example](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/dev-2.x/examples/finite_state_machine_example.py) which can help you discover almost everything that FSM has.